# How to pass exception object through query string

Tags: c#, asp.net, object, global-asax

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    Exception objException = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();        
    Server.Transfer("~/ErrorPage/Error_Page.aspx?objException=" 
                        + objException,true);
}

//Error page.aspx page load
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    object objException = Request.QueryString["objException"];
    //Write exception in log file.
    WriteApplicationErrorLog(objException.Message, objException.StackTrace);
}
```

I am getting an exception object in `Global.asax` on application level. I need to pass this exception object to a page `errorpage.aspx`, and write it to a log file.

I am using the code above, but getting the exception message, and not the object.

Comment: Why not log the exception in that `Application_Error` and *then* redirect to the error page?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a class and pass the exception object to it to log it but if you want to pass it to error page any way then you can store exception object in session and access that in error page.

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    Session["YourException"] =  Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
    Server.Transfer("~/ErrorPage/Error_Page.aspx?objException=" 
                        + objException,true);
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception objException = (Exception ) Session["YourException"];

    //Write exception in log file
    WriteApplicationErrorLog(objException.Message, objException.StackTrace);
}
```

Comment: without session is possible